# SQL Show two text and their values as one in my view

Tags: sql, case

I am looking to show "Carers Paid" and "Carers Unpaid" to show as a Carers Leave in my view.

below is my code

```
SELECT a.EmployeeUID AS [Employee ID]
       ,b.LongName AS [Leave type] (here i wanna show two leave type as one mentioned above)
       ,a.Mins AS [Leave balance
FROM   [dbo].[AbsenceBalance] a 
JOIN   [dbo].[AbsenceTypes] b ON     a.AbsenceTypesUID = b.UID
WHERE  b.UID IN (3,4,5,6,7)
```

Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/362Zd.png)

Comment: Provide expected result

Comment: The Image you provide is another table?

Comment: a and b are poor table aliases. Chose something that makes sense, like `ab` for AbsenceBalance.